# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\resources\views\keuangan\hasil.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

i am beginner in laravel. I want to update a data but I get an error like this : Trying to get property 'id' of non-object'

This is my Controller :

```
    public function hitung(Request $request)
    {

        $tanggal = date("Y-m-d");

        $keuangan = array(
            'bahan_baku'                => $request->bahan_baku,
            'biaya_tambahan'            => $request->biaya_tambahan,
            'jumlah_tempe'              => $request->jumlah_tempe,
            'biaya_produksi'            => $request->bahan_baku + $request->biaya_tambahan,
            'hasil_penjualan'           => $request->jumlah_tempe * 1000,
            'hasil_pendapatan'          => ($request->jumlah_tempe * 1000) - ($request->bahan_baku + $request->biaya_tambahan),
            'tanggal'                   => $tanggal,
        );
        
        Keuangan::create($keuangan);

        return view('keuangan.hasil', compact('keuangan'));

    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $keuangan = Keuangan::find($id);
        return view('/keuangan/edit', compact('keuangan'));
    }
}
```

This is section from my view :

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title','Manajemen Keuangan')

@section('content')
<div class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <div class="form-group">
              <h4>Keuangan :<strong style="color: red;"> {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse( $keuangan['tanggal'] )->translatedFormat("d F Y") }} </strong></h4>
            </div>

            <table class="table table-borderless">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><strong>Biaya Produksi</strong></td>
                  <td>: &nbsp&nbsp Rp. {{ number_format($keuangan['biaya_produksi']) }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><strong>Hasil Penjualan</strong></td>
                  <td>: &nbsp&nbsp Rp. {{ number_format($keuangan['hasil_penjualan']) }}</td>
                </tr>
                <td><hr></td>
                <td><hr align="left" style="width: 25%;"></td>
                <tr>
                  <td><strong>Hasil Pendapatan</strong></td>
                  <td>: &nbsp&nbsp Rp. {{ number_format($keuangan['hasil_pendapatan']) }}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            @if($keuangan)
            <a href="/keuangan/{{ $keuangan->id }}/edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
            @endif
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@stop
```

this is my route :

```
  Route::get('/keuangan/edit/{id}', 'KeuanganController@edit');
```

this is section from my model :

class Keuangan extends Model

```
{
    protected $table = 'keuangan';
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'bahan_baku', 'biaya_tambahan', 'biaya_produksi', 'jumlah_tempe', 'hasil_penjualan', 'hasil_pendapatan'];
}
```

where is my fault ?? I just want to make an edit to the my data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this return model instance not only array. becouse array don't have id

```php
public function hitung(Request $request)
{

    $tanggal = date("Y-m-d");

    $keuangan = array(
        'bahan_baku'                => $request->bahan_baku,
        'biaya_tambahan'            => $request->biaya_tambahan,
        'jumlah_tempe'              => $request->jumlah_tempe,
        'biaya_produksi'            => $request->bahan_baku + $request->biaya_tambahan,
        'hasil_penjualan'           => $request->jumlah_tempe * 1000,
        'hasil_pendapatan'          => ($request->jumlah_tempe * 1000) - ($request->bahan_baku + $request->biaya_tambahan),
        'tanggal'                   => $tanggal,
    );

    $keuangan = Keuangan::create($keuangan); // send this

    return view('keuangan.hasil', compact('keuangan'));
}
```